# Problems to print with Canon MP250

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have a Canon MP250 printer and I want to use it with my Ubuntu Studio 15.10 installation.

Even the fact that the system recognized and installed the printer, I can not to print anything.

When I want to perform a "testing page", the printer gives an error code (according to the printer manual, this code is about the ink level of the cartridges, which is absurd because the cartridges are full).

I tested the printer with a computer with Windows 7 (and the Canon driver for Windows), and the printer worked so fine!!!

SO... There is something wrong with my Ubuntu printer driver to this device... But I don't know how to fix it!!!

The curious thing is... I can scan documents with this printer with my Ubuntu Studio 15.10 installation!!!

So... It is something related with the printing part, only.

Please, I need help, here!!!